# Center of mass computation yields wrong results in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, centroid

I will start by stating that I'm slowly going insane. I am trying to extract contours from an image and compute their centers of mass using Java and OpenCV.

For all the inner contours, the results are correct, however for the outer (largest) contour, the centroid is way, way off. The input image, the code and the output result are all below. OpenCV version is 3.1.

Others have had this problem and the suggestions were to:

1. Check if the contour is closed. It is, I checked.
2. Use Canny to detect edges before extracting contours. I don't understand why that's necessary, but I tried it and the result is that it messes up the tree hierarchy since it generates two contours for each edge, which is not something I want.

The input image is very large (27MB) and the weird part is that when I resized it to 1000x800, the center of mass suddenly got computed correctly, however, I need to be able to process the image at the original resolution.

```
/*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.philrovision.dxfvision.matching;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Moments;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 *
 * @author rhobincu
 */
public class MomentsNGTest {

    @Test
    public void testOpenCvMoments() {
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("moments_fail.png");
        Mat channel = new Mat();
        Core.extractChannel(image, channel, 1);
        Mat mask = new Mat();
        Imgproc.threshold(channel, mask, 191, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

        Mat filteredMask = new Mat();
        Imgproc.medianBlur(mask, filteredMask, 5);

        List<MatOfPoint> allContours = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

        Imgproc.findContours(filteredMask, allContours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE,
                Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0, 0));

        MatOfPoint largestContour = allContours.stream().max((c1, c2) -> {
            double area1 = Imgproc.contourArea(c1);
            double area2 = Imgproc.contourArea(c2);
            if (area1 < area2) {
                return -1;
            } else if (area1 > area2) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }).get();

        Mat debugCanvas = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Imgproc.drawContours(debugCanvas, Arrays.asList(largestContour), -1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 3);
        Imgproc.drawMarker(debugCanvas, getCenterOfMass(largestContour),
                new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        Rect boundingBox = Imgproc.boundingRect(largestContour);
        Imgproc.rectangle(debugCanvas, boundingBox.br(), boundingBox.tl(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
        System.out.printf("Bounding box area is: %f and contour area is: %f", boundingBox.area(), Imgproc.contourArea(
                largestContour));
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("output.png", debugCanvas);

    }

    private static Point getCenterOfMass(MatOfPoint contour) {
        Moments moments = Imgproc.moments(contour);
        return new Point(moments.m10 / moments.m00, moments.m01 / moments.m00);
    }
}
```

Input: (full image [here](http://users.dcae.pub.ro/~rhobincu/moments_fail.png))
[image]
Output:
[image]

STDOUT:

```
Bounding box area is: 6460729,000000 and contour area is: 5963212,000000
```

The centroid is drawn close to the upper left corner, outside the contour.

Comment: Not sure if something is wrong with OpenCV's implementation, but your code looks good. You *can* [manually calculate](http://aishack.in/tutorials/image-moments/) the moments. One question though, why mask and then blur instead of blur and then mask? Non-binary mask is somewhat a misnomer.

Comment: Yeah something's not right here. I just implemented [a Python version](https://gist.github.com/alkasm/4471492903c64875f4fbdaef3034e938) of your code more or less line-for-line and [got the expected result](https://imgur.com/a/zXzNg).

Comment: Do you get an accurate `contourArea`?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Hello and thanks for trying to help. I have updated the text with answers to your questions. The blur is median so the output should still be a binary image since all it does is replace pixels with other pixels. The contour area value looks legit. Can you confirm that you tested with the full-size original image (27MB)?

Comment: Also, what OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: Actually, with the image downloaded from this question, the code works, because the input image got compressed a lot. I'm trying to upload the full input image.

Comment: Edit---just saw your comment. You're right, it wasn't at all the full image---just a measly 500kb. Stack has a 2mb limit and Imgur's overall limit is 20mb. You'll need to find a different host (maybe one of the popular online drive apps). I'm using OpenCV 3.2. Also good call re: `medianBlur`, was thinking Gaussian.

Comment: Added a link to full sized input image.

Comment: Great, thanks. My code still works on the full-res version as well. It looks like there was a [related issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6350) specifically in the Java implementation on OpenCV's GitHub that was solved with [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/6351) simple pull request. Stuff was being cast to `int` that shouldn't have been. Upgrading OpenCV should fix you up. Or if you really want to, you can edit your library files with the simple fix (literally just removing an `int` cast on a few lines).

Comment: Wow, so I'm not crazy! I don't know how you found that, I have been searching for an explanation for the last 8 hours. Please add an answer so I can mark it as correct. Thank you!

Comment: If you're ever looking to see if you found a bug, go to the Github, go into issues, and you can search the issues (usually just searching the function name is enough) and browsing through some of them. But make sure you remove the default `is:open` in case the issue was previously solved. I will add it as an answer. You're not crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment discussion, it looks like this issue you're having [was reported](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6350) specifically in the Java implementation on OpenCV's GitHub. It was eventually solved with [this simple pull request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/6351). There were some unnecessary `int` castings.

Possible solutions then:

1. Upgrading OpenCV should fix you up.
2. You can edit your library files with the fix (it's simply removing an `(int)` cast on a few lines).
3. Define your own function to calculate the centroids.

---

If you're bored and want to figure out 3, it's actually not a difficult calculation:

Centroids of a contour are usually calculated from [image moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment). As shown on that page, a moment `M_ij` can be defined on images as:

```
M_ij = sum_x sum_y (x^i * y^j * I(x, y))
```

and the centroid of a binary shape is

```
(x_c, y_c) = (M_10/M_00, M_01/M_00)
```

Note that `M_00 = sum_x sum_y (I(x, y))` which, in a binary 0 and 1 image, is just the number of white pixels. If your `contourArea` is working as you stated in the comments, you can simply use that as `M_00`. Then note also that `M_10` is just the sum of the `x` values corresponding to white pixels and `M_01` with the `y` values. These can be easily calculated, and you can define your own centroid function with the contours.

Comment: I can confirm now that the code works as expected with OpenCV 3.2.0.